# Is nullifying every views and listeners a good idea in finding or correcting leaks?

Tags: android, memory-leaks

I am working on a project and I keep seeing methods that nullify the views and listeners on every onDestroy(). I have even seen code that navigate the rootView and set every listener to null.

The original coder told me that he has done it that way to prevent leaks, but I think it is causing more harm to the VM. What do you think?

Comment: Sounds like the original coder had a leak, and attempted to resolve it by pruning all of the children away, instead of finding the root problem. Tools like Eclipse MAT can help identify what's preventing memory from being released.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, it is unnecessary. Once the activity is destroyed (i.e. **onDestroy** is called) then all the views and its related listeners are qualified for garbage collection.

However, make sure you are not treating anything `static` with activity and/or anything that is bound to activity's context (that includes Views too).

Answer (score 1):

Most Android-related memory leaks are related to incorrect usage of event buses (forgetting to unsubscribe something), or from implicit reference to a context (`public class Blah extends AsyncTask<?,?,?>`), or static reference to the Activity (because who knows why, everybody knows that's a terrible idea).

Nulling out your views won't help you find any of that.

You can however use [LeakCanary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary) library which traces memory leaks for you automatically.

Answer (score 0):

It may cause the GC to make the used memory be reuseable faster, but its not something i would do since its tedious and a waste of time.

If you want to prevent memory leaks you should used tools like LeakCanary or MAT or alike, or\and be well aware of diffrent Android components lifecycles and know what you are doing when using static variables. It is less likely that that guy avoided a memory leak, unless he references Android components in static fields (which is a bad idea anyway).